# WooCommerce Subscriptions - Action on initial payment

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am using the WooCommerce subscriptions plugin, in particular the `woocommerce_subscription_payment_complete` function.

I am using it like this:

```
add_action('woocommerce_subscription_payment_complete','subscription_created');
function subscription_created($subscription) {
    echo 'Run when subscription payment is complete';
}
```

This works, but it also fires when a renewal payment completes.  Does anybody know of a way to determine if the payment was for an initial subscription payment rather than a renewal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `woocommerce_checkout_subscription_created`, however the problem here is that it will fire before payment is processed - and I'm assuming you need to fire your even after payment has been successful.

One way to approach this is to set meta on the subscription post, that denotes whether your custom function has been run, and checking that meta with an `if` statement like this:

```
add_action('woocommerce_subscription_payment_complete','subscription_created');
function subscription_created($subscription) {
    //check if meta exists/is not true
    if (!get_post_meta($subscription->id, 'has_my_function_run', true)) {
        //update meta to bool(true)
        update_post_meta($subscription->id, 'has_my_function_run', true);
        //run your function
        echo 'Run when subscription payment is complete';
    }  
}
```

I am sure there is a better way to approach this though, so keep an eye out for other answers. It might be a good idea to look into hooking into `woocommerce_order_status_processing`, checking if it contains a subscription product, and then running your function, but that won't work if WooCommerce generates a new order for every subscription renewal.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I have ended up going down that route and checking for the presence of a custom field